# Where to put schema.org tags in HTML page?

Tags: seo, google-search, schema.org

Where should I put schema.org tags?
I have 3 options:

1. at detail page of article
2. at category page where are articles of
   category
3. at search page

Should I put schema.org tags on all these pages or?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Schema.org on all pages.

[Various consumers](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/54703/17633) might find it useful. Why should they have to visit a specific page to see your Schema.org markup for content they already see?

Just make sure that you don’t create several items for the same *thing* on the same page, unless you denote them as being about the same thing (e.g., with [Microdata’s `itemid`](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/58460/17633) or by using the same subject URI in RDFa).

You could use [`mainEntity`](http://schema.org/mainEntity)/[`mainEntityOfPage`](http://schema.org/mainEntityOfPage) to denote which item the page is primarily about.