# Should a personal website have the root page marked up as a schema.org 'Person'?

Tags: schema.org

The root page of a website (i.e. http://example.com/) is special in that it is the default landing page. It might contain a lot of different object types.

It might be considered a `Website`, or a `Blog` etc...

But should it also be marked up as the primary page for the given object. For example, a person might have a blog/website that has many pages - so should the root page be marked up as a Person and include the additional information?

Same applies for other `Things` like `Organisation`, `Book`, `Event` etc etc

Basically the idea is to indicate to things like Google that this root page on the website represents the primary place on the Internet for this person.  I.e., this is the persons website...

Comment: In case you don’t know it yet, Schema.org added a property that allows to denote that the `Person` is the primary entity of a page (see link in my answer).

Comment: Thanks for the update @unor - I had seen the update. I also spotted some new guidance on Google that said only the root page needs to have this markup.

Comment: Note that currently/probably [Google Search won’t display Rich Snippets for a website’s homepage](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35103577/1591669).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update**: Schema.org [added](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/81406/17633) properties that allow to denote the primary item: [`mainEntity` and `mainEntityOfPage`](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/87982/17633)

---

Schema.org doesn’t provide a way to mark a `Person` item as the main item of the page. [`WebPage`](http://schema.org/WebPage)’s [`mainContentOfPage` property](http://schema.org/mainContentOfPage) can not have a value like `Person`. However, it gets [discussed](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-vocabs/2014May/0248.html) to make this possible (e.g., by changing `mainContentOfPage`’s range to `Thing`).

So consumers (like search engines) have currently no definite way to know that an item is the "main" content of a page, they can only make guesses.

In general, if all of your pages contain information about you, all of your pages [could/should](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23432974/1591669) have a `Person` item, not only the page you consider to be "canonical".

So you could use `Person` on every page you authored (related via [`author` property](http://schema.org/author)), and give these `Person` items the root page URL as value for the [`url` property](http://schema.org/url).