# Why aren't my rating/review Google rich snippets working?

Tags: seo, rich-snippets, google-rich-snippets

I'm using Google rich snippets (https://developers.google.com/structured-data/rich-snippets/reviews) to tag ratings and reviews on this website: http://www.fwpest.com/

Google's Structured Data Testing Tool says "All good" here: https://developers.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool/?url=http://fwpest.com

But I **don't** see the stars below the website url on a Google SRP here:
https://www.google.com/search?q=f%26w%20pest%20control

By contrast, I **do** see the star rating and review metadata displayed for the ContactUs and BBB pages.

Why stars for ContactUs and BBB pages but no stars for fwpest.com?

[image: Google SRP result screenshot]

Answer (score 2):

Google Search doesn’t seem to show Rich Snippets for homepages.

This is currently not documented, but [confirmed by the Google employee @methode](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31616800/1591669):

> We (Google) don't accept rich snippets for homepages; rich snippet annotations should be placed on leaf pages.

Comment: Thanks. Leaf pages not working either. Eg: https://www.google.com/search?&q=f%26w%20pest%20control%20contact

Comment: Sorry - fuller response: Thanks but I'm not sure that is the answer in this case. Leaf pages are not working either. Eg: https://www.google.com/search?&q=f%26w%20pest%20control%20contact  
That leaf page checks out ok on the Google Structured Data Checker - https://developers.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool/?

Comment: @user2916527: It seems that you have the same reviews/ratings on each page, in the sidebar. Would you expect that Google Search displays the corresponding Rich Snippet for each of your pages? Or in other words: Why should they display it for your contact page? To me it seems to be secondary information, not really relevant to that page. -- Anyway, digging further seems to require SEO advice (which is off-topic on SO), and might be a better fit for [webmasters.se].

Comment: Thanks unor and will do - I didn't know about Webmasters.