# Why Google doesn't show review/rating with stars?

Tags: html, seo, schema.org, microdata, google-rich-snippets

After readings on [schema.org](https://schema.org/AggregateRating) I wrote a small "rich snippet" or what ever it is called. We were found today by google, but no stars and ratings were shown. Maybe someone has expierence with it and know how things are done? Does it only depends on microdata or also on anything else in `<head>` tags? Otherwise what is wrong with my snippet?

Here is my snippet:

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Organization">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="clogo-container">
                <img src="logo.jpg" alt="logo" class="logo" />
            </div>
            <div class="infos">
                <span class="website"><a href="https://localhost" target="_blank">https://localhost</a></span><br/>
                is a page made by<br/>
                <br/>
                <span class="name" itemprop="name"><b>Mypage</b></span><br/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="rate" itemprop="aggregateRating" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/AggregateRating">
                <div class="ratingbox">
                    <img src="image.jpg" alt="Logo" />
                    <b><span class="name">Mypage</span></b>
                    <div class="main-rating" id="customer-1-rate"></div>
                    <span class="vote">
                        <span itemprop="ratingValue">4.44</span>
                        <meta itemprop="bestRating" content="5"/>
                        <meta itemprop="worstRating" content="1"/>
                        / 5.00</span><br/>
                        <span class="total">out of
                            <span itemprop="ratingCount">34</span>
                        total</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your use of Microdata and Schema.org seems to be fine, and Google’s [SDTT](https://developers.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool/) reports no issues and says that you provide all necessary data for their [Aggregate Ratings Rich Snippet](https://developers.google.com/structured-data/rich-snippets/reviews#aggregate_ratings). So technically everything seems to be correct.

That means the issue (that you don’t see a Rich Snippet for your result) probably has to do with Google’s policies. There are [various possible reasons why a search result feature doesn’t get displayed](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/89650/17633) for a result. And note that they never guarantee displaying one, even if everything is correct.

Typical (but not the only) reasons:

- You have to wait longer. It can take a long time (after indexing) until Rich Snippets appear.
- You checked the search result for your homepage (or you only have this markup on your homepage). [Google doesn’t show Rich Snippets for homepages](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35103577/1591669).
- Your page content doesn’t "look like" it contains aggregated ratings, or your hide them visually.

Comment: `The highest/lowest value allowed in this rating system. * Required if the rating system is not a 5-point scale. If bestRating/worstRating is omitted, 5 is assumed.` from [Enabling Rich Snippet](https://developers.google.com/structured-data/rich-snippets/reviews#wzxhzdk8aggregateratingwzxhzdk9_type_definition). Could this make issue somehow? I am using those and my highest/lowest rate values are 5/1.

Comment: @ksno: I don’t think so. Even though Schema.org defines default values in case the properties are not specified (and Google follows that), there is nothing wrong with specifying values matching these defaults explicitly.

Comment: thank you for your help. google shows our rich snippets now. It toke some time.

Comment: how much time did it take for you for ratings to be visible?